# Authentication and Authorization with django-oauth-toolkit

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, django-oauth

i've some question for python and django developers, i'm build a system API application with DRF, i've some problems about authorization and authentication, i don't wanna use patterns of django for it instead of this patterns i will use **OAUTH 2.0** and maybe i little **JWT**(JSON Web Token), but i need know:
1) Between django-oauth-toolkit and django-rest-auth what's best Lib?
2)It's better use **django-oauth-toolkit** for authentication and authorization, if not which is the best Lib?
3)How i integrate django-oauth-toolkit with django-allauth, it's possible and secure to use both?
4)I've others questions about it, that could be solved later!

Thanks for attention...

Comment: i'm trying to use django-oauth-tookit for authorization, django-allauth for social integrations and maybe django-rest-framework-jwt if it needs

Comment: please i need your help, i searched a lot too to understand when use DOT and django-allauth, if you can explain it to me, i'll be gratful a lot

Comment: Everything depends on the use case... Your application (front+backend) will work on the same ip/domain ? Your application will be used as an authentication server means that any other sites/applications will use Your application for authentication ?

Comment: my backend was developed by python/django and my frontend will be developed by javascript/React, later i'll have a app native for Android and iOS, work on the same ip/domain depends on, if it possible yes will work, so i need authorization and authentication for web and can work on android

Comment: django-allauth can solve all problems or i'll need use django-oauth-toolkit for server and django-allauth will authenticate users by social accounts?

Comment: I think django-allauth can solve all problems after fast docs read.

Comment: now, i wanna know how use django-allauth in native apps Android and iOS, i read the docs but i didn't find how do it

Comment: React is for web application. You need to start from here and try to auth user between browser and backend. Then you can try to export and build this web app in android studio/xcode using "react-native" and make hope everything will work fine.

Comment: when i create android app authorization can come by django-allauth?

Comment: No. You need to understand - in this architecture - django with django-allauth plugin needs to stay somewhere on the server with accessible API (like django rest framework) and Android/iOS is a different application (client) which will call this API.
1. Client calls server with django by url something like /api/login/ (with username and password).
2. Server will response with auth token and you need to use this token for further requests. There is no "django" on front apps (ios, android, browser). Front is a one thing and API is second.

Comment: django-allauth hasn't a server but django-oauth-toolkit has, so who will work with authentication and authorization (DOT or django-allauth).

Comment: you can send me a code explaining how it will work?